# Wicket alike property substitution

Tags: java, wicket, el

When reading properties in a Wicket Application we can have properties like this and the values will be automatically replaced with the values of the model object.

```
 weather.message=Weather station reports that the temperature is ${currentTemperature} ${units}
```

Now I want to use something similar in a non-wicket application, but can't find a library to do it. I looked at commons-configuration, but it seems very complicate compared to how easy it is to set it up with Wicket.

Comment: You could use Wicket for this (seems a bit overkill, but hey ;))